# How to split bulk video fast by using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a lot of videos, so I want to split them automatically. And they will be divided into 2 parts:

- Part 1: 15 minutes
- Part 2: the rest

Searched a lot, but did not find. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-ss` and `-t` options:

```
ffmpeg -i input -t 00:15:00 -codec copy output
ffmpeg -ss 00:15:00 -i input -codec copy output
```

From the [FFmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

```
   -ss position (input/output)
       When used as an input option (before "-i"), seeks in this input
       file to position. Note the in most formats it is not possible to
       seek exactly, so ffmpeg will seek to the closest seek point before
       position.  When transcoding and -accurate_seek is enabled (the
       default), this extra segment between the seek point and position
       will be decoded and discarded. When doing stream copy or when
       -noaccurate_seek is used, it will be preserved.

       When used as an output option (before an output filename), decodes
       but discards input until the timestamps reach position.

       position may be either in seconds or in "hh:mm:ss[.xxx]" form.

   -t duration (output)
       Stop writing the output after its duration reaches duration.
       duration may be a number in seconds, or in "hh:mm:ss[.xxx]" form.

       -to and -t are mutually exclusive and -t has priority.
```

The example uses `-codec copy` to use [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode instead of re-encoding.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you show me how to split batch with ffmpeg, please ?

Comment: @user3513568 You did not provide enough information to give you a more detailed answer. What is your OS? Do you want to re-encode the outputs, or do you want to stream copy? If you want to re-encode, what video, audio, and container formats do you want the output to be? Are all of the inputs in one directory?

Comment: Hi, I use windows OS. All of the inputs in one directory and I want to use stream copy because it is so fast. Thanks !

Comment: possibly the segment muxer (though in my experience cutting it several times in a row is lightning fast anyway)? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1504