# Speeding up the doinbackground() process

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm splitting an encrypted video into 4 parts using this code

```
public class SplitVideoFile {
private static String result;
static  ArrayList<String>update=new ArrayList<>();
public static String main(File file) {

    try {
       // File file = new File("C:/Documents/Despicable Me 2 - Trailer (HD) - YouTube.mp4");//File read from Source folder to Split.
        if (file.exists()) {

            String videoFileName = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")); // Name of the videoFile without extension
           // String path = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/storage/emulated/0/Videointegrity";
            String path =  "/storage/emulated/0/Videointegrity";
          //  File myDir = new File(getFile, "folder");
            //myDir.mkdir();

            File splitFile = new File(path.concat("/").concat(videoFileName));//Destination folder to save.
            if (!splitFile.exists()) {
                splitFile.mkdirs();
                Log.d("Directory Created -> ", splitFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            int i = 01;// Files count starts from 1
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            String videoFile = splitFile.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ String.format("%02d", i) +"_"+ file.getName();// Location to save the files which are Split from the original file.
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
            Log.d("File Created Location: ", videoFile);
            update.add("File Created Location: ".concat(videoFile));
            int totalPartsToSplit =4 ;// Total files to split.
            int splitSize = inputStream.available() / totalPartsToSplit;
            int streamSize = 0;
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = inputStream.read()) != -1) {

                if (splitSize == streamSize) {
                    if (i != totalPartsToSplit) {
                        i++;
                        String fileCount = String.format("%02d", i); // output will be 1 is 01, 2 is 02
                        videoFile = splitFile.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ fileCount +"_"+ file.getName();
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
                        Log.d("File Created Location: ", videoFile);
                        streamSize = 0;
                    }
                }
                outputStream.write(read);
                streamSize++;
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();

            Log.d("Total files Split ->", String.valueOf(totalPartsToSplit));
        result="success";
        } else {
            System.err.println(file.getAbsolutePath() +" File Not Found.");
            result="failed";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
public ArrayList<String> getUpdate()
{
    return update;
}
```

And in my activity file i call this using async task's doinbackground method like below

```
 protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG + " DoINBackGround", "On doInBackground...");
        File encvideo=new File(epath.getText().toString());
        SplitVideoFile split=new SplitVideoFile();
        String result=split.main(encvideo);
        publishProgress(1);
        return result;
    }
```

Even though it splits the video, it takes too much of time to do the process.
How can I speed them up. As I'm showing a progress bar in preexecute method it looks like the user sees the progress bar for a long time, which I don't want.

Comment: You have to debug and check the splitting code where it is taking the most time

Comment: video splitting is time consumable task and its depends on devices specification like processor, you cannot handle this performance by code. Also you can try FFMPEG for video operation. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952639